# How to return the value of Data Reader(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, return-value

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string sCurr = "";
    string myConString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=localhost;Port=0000;DATABASE=ABC;UID=root;PASSWORD=123;OPTION=3;";

    OdbcConnection dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(myConString);
    dbConnection.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM USER";
    OdbcConnection conn = null;
    OdbcCommand comm = null;
    OdbcDataReader dr = null;
    conn = new OdbcConnection(myConString);
    conn.Open();
    comm = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr != null)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            sCurr = (dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

I want to get value[2] and value[4] for checking purpose.

How to get the value ?

Please Help!

Thank you.

**dr = comm.ExecuteReader(); have value like image below:**

[image: Record In Data Reader]

Comment: Never use `SELECT *` in a query used with a `DataReader` because you won't know what columns will be at what locations. Always use explicit column names (e.g. if the table design changes then your query will break).

Comment: @Dai i already add 2column names.. but i don't know how to display it ...  i alway use response.write(before i use asp.net MVC) to check value .... how display in my index.cshtml (/Home/Index)?

Comment: Never use `Response.Write` inside an ASP.NET MVC Controller action method. Return all rendered data using a View-Model object to the View.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give a full example.

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure your `IDisposable` objects are disposed-of before returning with a `using()` block. Otherwise you will potentially leak native resources and memory (e.g. you may prematurely exhaust your DbConnection pool).
- Your code is defining empty `Odbc...` objects for no reason.
- Use `async` for all IO where possible - as you're using ASP.NET this is supported (note that you cannot have *concurrent* `async` with ADO.NET objects whereas you can with filesystem IO on Windows).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    const string connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=localhost;Port=0000;DATABASE=ABC;UID=root;PASSWORD=123;OPTION=3;";
    //const string sql = "SELECT * FROM USER"; // <-- don't do this. Always name your columns!
    const string sql = "SELECT UserId, Created, UserType, etc FROM `USER`":

    using( OdbcConnection c = new OdbcConnection( connectionString ))
    using( OdbcCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand() )
    {
        await c.OpenAsync();

        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        using( OdbcDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync() )
        {
            while( await rdr.ReadAsync() )
            {
                Int32 userId = rdr.GetInt32( 0 );
                DateTime created = rdr.GetDateTime( 1 );
                String userType = rdr.GetString( 2 );
                // etc...
            }
        }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

To return data to be rendered in the view, pass it using a View-Model:

```
class UserRow
{
    Int32    UserId  { get; set; }
    DateTime Created { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    const string connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}; SERVER=localhost;Port=0000;DATABASE=ABC;UID=root;PASSWORD=123;OPTION=3;";
    //const string sql = "SELECT * FROM USER"; // <-- don't do this. Always name your columns!
    const string sql = "SELECT UserId, Created, UserType, etc FROM `USER`":

    using( OdbcConnection c = new OdbcConnection( connectionString ))
    using( OdbcCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand() )
    {
        await c.OpenAsync();

        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        using( OdbcDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync() )
        {
            List<UserRow> list = new List<UserRow>();

            while( await rdr.ReadAsync() )
            {
                list.Add( new UserRow() {
                    UserId = rdr.GetInt32( 0 ),
                    Created = rdr.GetDateTime( 1 ),
                    // etc
                } );
            }

            return this.View( model: list );
        }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

```
@model IReadOnlyList<UserRow>

<div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UserID</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            etc
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach( UserRow row in this.Model )
{
        <tr>
            <td>@row.UserId</td>
            <td>@row.Created</td>
            etc
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>


</div>
```